# React JS - Error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when rendering a Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to render a table using ReactJS, but get an error -Cannot read property 'map' of undefined -

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Table.css'

const obj = [{
    name: "onion",
    price: ".99",
    id: 1
}, {
    name: "pepper",
    price: "1.25",
    id: 2
}, {
    name: "broccoli",
    price: "3.00",
    id: 3
}];

class TableRow extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {
            data
        } = this.props;
        const row = data.map((data) =>
            <tr>
                <td key={data.name}>{data.name}</td>
                <td key={data.id}>{data.id}</td>
                <td key={data.price}>{data.price}</td>
            </tr>
        );
        return (
            <span>{row}</span>
        );
    }
}

class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <TableRow data={this.props.data} />
            </table>
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

I imported the table component into the App.js file. However, the error occurs on the following line of Table.js: const row = data.map((data) =>
...could I get some assistance please?

Comment: could you also share the App.js so that we can see what kind of data type you are passing as a prop to <Table /> component?

Comment: It seems like your `data` is `undefined`. Are you sure you are getting the data at the time of the render?

Comment: Where are you giving `Table` its `data` prop? Is that `data` an array? As an aside, `data.map((data) => ---)` is wrong, you can't define 2 variables with the same name in the same scope

Comment: Is `const obj = ...` the same thing as `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `table` class, change the below code from    `<TableRow data={this.props.data} />` to `<TableRow data={obj} />`.

You defined `obj` but you never use it anywhere. When the program rendering your `table` class, and trying to render `TableRow`, it pass data using `data` prop. But you're passing using `this.props.data` where you don't have the data for it, and hence when `TableRow` trying to apply `map` function it hits exception

Comment: Thank you, that edit resolved the issue I was encountering; Thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not passing an array down into `Table` as `data`.

The Table component should be set in App.js or where you're using it like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Table data={[1,5,6,etc. . .]} /> \\data has an array of whatever values you care for.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Afterwards you will also have another problem because you should not be setting `data = this.props` in `TableRow`. `data` should be set to `this.props.data` like so:

```
const {
        data
    } = this.props.data;
```